# Resource names are shown instead of labels

Tags: react-admin

Suddenly my react-admin started to act weird. It shows resource names instead of labels:

[image: Example]

My code hasn't changed, all the labels are there.

E.g.:

```
                 <Resource name="ads" options={{ label: 'Hirdetések' }} list={AdList} edit={AdEdit} create={AdCreate} show={AdShow} icon={PostIcon}/>,
                 permissions === 'admin' ? <Resource name="users" options={{ label: 'Felhasználók' }} list={UserList} show={UserShow} edit={UserEdit} create={UserCreate} icon={UserIcon}/> : null,
                 <Resource name="clicks" options={{ label: 'Legutóbbi kattintások' }} list={ClickList} />,
                 <Resource name="clicksmonthly" options={{ label: 'Havi összesítés' }} list={ClicksmonthlyList} />,
                 permissions === 'admin' ? <Resource name="leads" options={{ label: 'Legutóbbi leadek' }} list={LeadList} /> : null,
```

Also the Buttons do not show the Button titles, they show resource names as well.

Why? I know this is a bit silly question, but if I did not do anything, why did it suddenly change?

I am using react-admin 2.8.5 with react version 16.8.2

```
"react": "^16.8.2",
"react-admin": "^2.8.5",
"react-dom": "^16.8.2",
"react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
```

Comment: Hi Reka, you have something wrong with the resource translation system,
see here how this is done by "Translating Resource and Field Names": https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html

Comment: hi Max, It seems something's with the react-admin version I use, as I restarted the whole project of mine with the Tutorial (completely restarted from scratch, fetching  the example API, etc ), and I have the very same issue with it as well. I'm gonna send a bug report to the developers on github ...

Comment: Hi Reka, I worked with 2.8.5, now I use 2.8.6, but I do not have this problem. Are there any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: See this post: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3105#issuecomment-480526044

Comment: yes, this is what i've found as well, and linked it here as an answer, but got deleted by others. thanks for your help tho.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete **node_modules** folder and **.lock** file
- install dependencies again e.g. `yarn install` or `npm install`